# Convert nested XML file to some kind of database format and displaying on website

Tags: database, server, frontend, backend

Heyos!

I am in sincere need of help and advice with a project I have to work on.
Let me give you a brief overview:

### **Context:**

*MeSH-Browser* is a website used for displaying "[...] hierarchically-organized terminology for indexing and cataloging of biomedical information [...]" (see: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/).
The *MeSH-data* can be downloaded from here: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/download_mesh.html

### **What is the task:**

- Displaying *MeSH-data*  on a website.

### **What is given:**

- *MeSH-data* as mentioned above (see: https://www.nlm.nih.gov/mesh/download_mesh.html).

### **What is the catch:**

- I have no experience in developing a back- and frontend.

### **What I have come up so far:**

I figured out that I need to develop a back- and frontend as well as the communication between those.

1. Convert given *MeSH-data* in .xml format to database input format.
2. Create a server running a database fed with the converted *MeSH-data*.
3. Communication between database and website.
4. A website for displaying the data stored in the database.

After googling I found a GitHub project with "Code and documentation for the release of MeSH in RDF format" (see: https://github.com/HHS/meshrdf/).
Hence I set up a virtual machine running an ubuntu server and installed *OpenLink's Virtuoso software* (see: https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/), which can be used for querying the resulting RDF.
What has to be done next is integrating the converted *MeSH-data* in RDF into the *Virtuoso* database (have not looked into this yet).

Considering the communication with the frontend, I was thinking about using one of the libraries mentioned on https://www.w3.org/community/rdfjs/wiki/Comparison_of_RDFJS_libraries and query the data with the help of *SPARQL*.

As frontend I would use *ReactJS* as I find it appealing to me.

That is all for now, what are your opinions?

Please do note that this is only for educational purposes.